# Can't get response from imgur api

Tags: node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, router, axios

I'm trying to get a response from the imgur api, and I'm having trouble getting anything. I keep getting 401 not authorized errors. I've also tried using `".../gallery/authorization?client_id=###########/search="+req.body.search` and that doesn't work either. I'm not really understanding the documentation. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Oh, btw this is written in express/node.js.

```
 router.post('/getimages', function(req,res,next){
      console.log('successfully got to /getimages backend :P');
      console.log('the value of the search query is ', req.body.search);
      var url = 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q='+req.body.search;
      axios.get(url)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log('YATA from axios to imgur');
        console.log(response);
          res.json({'YATA':'YATA from getimages'});
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('Fail from axios request to imgur');
        console.log(error);
          res.json({'OHNOES':'NOOOOYATA from getimages'});
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://api.imgur.com/#authentication), you have to [register your app](https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient) to use the API.  This is even if you'll be using it in an anonymous capacity, which they seem to allow.

Comment: Sure, that's what I was doing with the client id but I couldn't get that to work either.

Comment: You were trying to send it as a query when it should be in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `clientId` in the authorization header  :

```
axios = require("axios");

search = "monkey";
clientId = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";

axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q=' + search,
    headers: { 'authorization': 'Client-ID ' + clientId }
}).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Yep that was it. Thanks.